# Can I call Java swing in JSP or servlet without using applet

Tags: java, swing, jsp

Can I use the Java swing API from a JSP or servlet outside of an applet context? e.g. Suppose I make a frame and I want this frame to popup when I click a button rendered by a JSP or servlet.

Comment: How can I play tennis on the moon whilst watching The Simpsons

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an urgent matter that will have little relevance to future visitors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display Swing components in a JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241342/is-it-possible-to-display-swing-components-in-a-jsp)

Answer (score 2):

If you call swing in jsp/servlet then your frame will open at server's operating system.

not at client side because you should know where jsp and servlets are run.
you better get knowledge of java webstart.

Comment: I got the requirement of finger print authentication where I have a JSP page there is a button once I click that button Swing Application has to launch and take the finger print. As it is urgent for me If anyone can help me out will be appreciated much. thanks Sanjay

Comment: Actually, it’s very likely that the attempt of opening a frame will cause a `HeadlessException`. But that depends on the server environment.

Comment: @Serene: you are asking a new question in a comment. That’s a really bad strategy if you want answers.

Answer (score 1):

As you know **Swing** is used to create Desktop application & it comes under Core Java. Where as, **JSP** is a part of J2EE. It is designed to access application world wide via Internet. It requires application servers like Tomcat, WebLogic, WebSphere, etc.

You want run a desktop application on browser. To do this you can use **Java Web Start Software**. It is a part of [Java SE 6 - Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html). *Java Web Start allows you to launch a standalone Java application on web browser*. It uses an XML file called `JNLP Descriptor` to tell Java Web Start  software to download, cache, and run the application.

Suppose your Java application is JNLPExample & want to run it on Tomcat server. Then you need to create a JNLP file like below :-

**JNLPExample.jnlp :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="JNLPExample.jnlp">

     <information>
          <title>JNLP Example</title>
          <vendor>Java Code Geeks</vendor>
          <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
          <description>JNLP Testing</description>
     </information>

     <security>
          <all-permissions/>
     </security>

     <resources>
          <j2se version="1.6+" />
          <jar href="JNLPExample.jar" />
     </resources>

     <application-desc main-class="main.javacodegeeks.JNLPExample" />
</jnlp>
```

Place `JNLPExample.jar` & `JNLPExample.jnlp` file under `C:\Tomcat\webapps\ROOT`

**XML Taken From :** [Sotirios-Efstathios Maneas Blog](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/web-start/java-web-start-getting-started/)

**Test application URL :** `http://localhost:8080/JNLPExample.jnlp`

To know more on Java Web start, How to create Java Web Start application, How to add keystore in .jar file, explore the below post :-

1. [Java Web Start – Getting Started - Sotirios-Efstathios Maneas](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/web-start/java-web-start-getting-started/)
2. [Java Web Start (Jnlp) Hello World Example - MKYong](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-web-start-jnlp-hello)
3. [Java Web Start - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)

Comment: But the OP wants to call from jsp or a servlet.

Comment: @Scary Wombat What is OP ?

Comment: @user000324, OP is short for "Original Poster", in this case it refers to Serene, who asked the question.